# Is this function monotonic or not?

Tags: calculus, monotone-functions

Consider a function $f$ as shown in figure.[image: Graph](It is a rough figure and hence not to scale)

The point $x = a$ is not in the domain of $f$ and function approaches $-\infty$ from left and $+\infty$ from right at $x = a$.

My teacher said that this type of function is a decreasing function because it's derivative is always negative. But I said that it's not monotonous because there exist infinitely many $a$,$b$ in domain of $f$ for which if $a<b$ then $f(a)<f(b)$ . So, please tell who is right ?

The actual function given to us was $f(x) = \sin x -3x + (x+1)^{-3}$ whose derivative is clearly always negative.

Comment: Your are absolutely right. Monotonicity is not **defined** using derivatives and your teacher is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @geetha290krm.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the notion of "monotonic function" was defined in your course. Generally (every single time I've seen the term "monotonic" used outside this question), monotonically increasing meant $a< b\implies f(a)\leq f(b)$ and strictly monotonically increasing meant $a< b\implies f(a)<f(b)$. It could be the case (yet unlikely) that your professor explicitly defined monotonic as a differentiable function for which it's derivative, from both sides, are either negative (or positive) or don't exist. This would be VERY non-standard.

Comment: Not sure why this answer was downvoted. It is perfectly correct.

Comment: I also agree it is correct, but I find geetha290krm's short and categorical comment more helpful.